# Game Engine & Language for beginners?

Tags: unity, c#

It would be great if someone who is experienced at game development would give me some insight and advice about game development. I'm studying computer science for 2 years now and game development is my biggest interest. Which is the best engine and programming language to start on? For indie game development, what engine would you recommend. I've been using Unity and C# for a month but I don't know if its the best option. Some tips or guidance on the topic would be thanked!

Comment: I'm sorry but this kind of questions are off-topic here. Check the FAQ. I suggest you use Reddit or similar forums for that kind of question

Comment: You can just check the help page, and [this page in there](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to see what types of questions are off-topic here. I'm flagging this as off-topic.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I'd recommend [GameMaker](https://www.yoyogames.com/gamemaker).  It's simple to use, but can do pretty well as your demands go up.  It's not a high end, super fancy 3D game engine, but that's not what making games is about necessarily.

Personally I'd start with a 2D style of game - something simple, like a side scroller or top down view game.  You'll learn a lot about the development and design, and then later you can move into 3D if you'd like. GameMaker can handle 3D, but if you want to go "fancy", you can move up to Unity.

The other suggestion I might make is to look into modding.  Get HalfLife 2, and start reading up on how to create mods for it.  Modding lets you leverage all the art and other resources that companies like Valve have made and shared, while using a decent game engine.  You can put your time into just level design if you'd like, or modelling and art (2D textures, 3D models), or even coding to extend the game if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks Tim!! Exactly the kind of guidance I was hoping. I will look into modding with out a doubt.

Comment: @MateoVillagomez It might be what you hoped for, but it might not be what you needed.

Comment: @TimHolt With your rep you should have known this was off topic...

Comment: I totally think people need to have support like this.  I think it's worth helping people with simple things.

I also put effort into describing what his goals should be - concentrating on the game idea, and not complexity of technology.   

We can do better than "GO AWAY" messages when people ask questions like this.

Comment: Everyone is a noob at some point. I agree with Tim, I get that 99% of times questions should be technical and specific but I also support the idea of helping people, who might not have all the answers as the ones that flag this question.

Comment: Answering off-topic questions encourages users to keep on asking off-topic questions. That's why there is a recommendation to _not_ answer these questions.

Answer (score -3):

In my opinion Unity3D is the best game engine, it has very good tools and optimization settings, I totally agree with you it’s a bit  hard to learn “, but it can give you large area of options , if you seriously interested in GameDev but you don’t want to write your own engine , Unity3d would be the best one.